# Meaning of Average Compares in BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am stuck with following question from the book 'Algorithms' 4th edition by Sedgewick and Wayne.

*Add to BST a recursive method avgCompares() that computes the average number
of compares required by a random search hit in a given BST (the internal path
length of the tree divided by its size, plus one). Develop two implementations: a recursive
method (which takes linear time and space proportional to the height), and a
method like size() that adds a field to each node in the tree (and takes linear space and
constant time per query).*

I am not clear on what the author mean by Average Compare in this question.

**Note:** I don't need assistance on coding part.

Comment: They want you to run Monte-Carlo simulation to compute average number of comparisons performed per search.

Answer (score 1):

To get the average number of compares for a BST you must sum the number of comparisons to find every node given that the length of search for every node is equal to internal path to that node + 1. Finally to get the average value you must divide the sum by the total number of nodes. So it is just the average length of a node search.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate it with an example?

Comment: Let's say you have an unbalanced BST of 3 nodes in the form of a list. You need 1 comparison to find node 1, 2 for node 2 and 3 for node 3. So you get the total of 6 comparisons to find every node in the BST. Divided by the number of nodes (3) it gives 2 as the average number of compares.